# What is the collective name for propositional and predicate logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I was devising a course for propositional logic and predicate logic. I have to give it a one-word name, not something like *Propositional and predicate logic*.

I want to give a name that encapsulates both these areas of logic. But I couldn't find any such name that is used to refer to both the areas of logic collectively.

I looked up the meaning of mathematical logic and it encapsulates quite a lot more than just propositional and predicate logic — it even encapsulates things such as set theory, model theory and so on and so forth.

I guess symbolic logic is the right name, but I am not 100% sure on it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Elementary Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=XU_m3HvrYFIC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: What is symbolic logic, just as general knowledge...??

Comment: Since Boole, every "modern logic" is symbolic: Classical, Intuitionistic, Modal, Epistemic, Model Th, Computability Th.

Comment: OK. So symbolic logic could once again mean a lot of things...

Comment: Thanks for the info...